# HAProxy - Add Trailing Slash

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I am working on a project where I need requests destined to a particular page to be routed to a separate backend.

For example, all requests for https://mycooldomain.com will go to backend "A". But, if navigating to https://mycooldomain.com/secretpage I want it to go to backend "B".

Now, I have this working but running into an issue where I need the trailing slash for this to work correctly.

So, I need a way to say if request is https://[whateverhostnameisused]/secretpage redirect to https://[whateverhostnameisused]/secretpage/.

Here is a sample of my config so far:

```
frontend f_https
    bind *:443 ssl crt cert.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https

    #define hosts
    acl host_a hdr(host) -i a.mycooldomain.com
    acl host_b hdr(host) -i b.mycooldomain.com
    acl host_c hdr(host) -i c.mycooldomain.com

    #custom acls
    acl secret path_beg -i /secretpage

    #Custom redirects

    ##define backend
    use_backend b_secret if secret
    use_backend b_a if host_a
    use_backend b_b if host_b
    use_backend b_c if host_c

    default_backend b_https

backend b_secret
    server secret 192.168.15.15:5575 check
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for something like this:

```
http-request redirect scheme https drop-query append-slash if { path -m str /secretpage }
```

This should work if applied to either the frontend or the backend.

http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4.2-redirect%20scheme

Specifying the scheme is only necessary because the syntax requires one of `location | prefix | scheme`, and with the other two options, you have to reassemble the URL yourself in the config.

---

Note also that `reqadd` is not officially deprecated, but the preferred way to add that request header is like this:

```
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
```

Note that no `:` is specified and the space after the header name must not be escaped with `\`.  This accomplishes the same result, but it uses a different code path inside HAProxy, and should be a more efficient operation.  You will want to use the the `http-request` and `http-response` directives instead of `reqxxx` and `rspxxx` where possible, as they are also better suited to more complex manipulations.

Comment: This worked perfect! Thank you very much for the detailed response and references to the documentation. I was getting close but hadn't tried this approach yet.